# How to respond when companies ask me why you are applying for a different role job when you're already employed in another role job?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, nepal

I currently work as system administrator in fintech company. Recently I applied for QA trainee role in another top company of Nepal(better than current one-if it matters, but I don't really care about that at this phase of my career).

In my current job, I am facing sideline. I am seeing diminishing chances of my placement in this company. Nobody except the manager is on my side. By nobody I mean junior and senior colleagues.

I don't talk much and I am shy and underconfident so I guess that is what is hampering my current life. Similarly, Another thing is I go to home exactly at 6 pm (The office is 9-6) because I need to go fast to reach the public transportation as public transportation in Nepal doesn't run after like 7pm.

They hate this one thing. And have already opened up to me about it.

So, I was applying as  a QA trainee role in that company. That company called me and asked why I was applying for QA trainee when I am already in a system admin job.

I told that it was because I was in probation period and still actively seeking for opportunities. Their response was like "wtf". So I guess  I did wrong.

What should I tell in these situations?

The thing is QA, system admin are similar skills to some extent. Both require linux. Both require sql. Both require automation etc.

Answer (score 6):

The standard answer (at least in Western culutre, not sure about Nepal) would be that you are pretty content with your current employment (badmouthing a past or current employer is a red flag for hiring managers), but that you realized that system administration isn't what you really want to do with your life and that you are looking for new and interesting challenges in quality assurance.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could explain what it is that interests/excites you about the position you're applying for. But that's true for all interviews.